# How to vectorize a function

Tags: r, data-science

I have a 5x4 matrix. I have created a function call fun1,  fun1 use double for loop to loop through the matrix and use distance function to work out the distance between two-row. The final results matrix will be a 5x5 matrix.
I am struggling to covert this fun1 to a vectorization function(no loop, only apply function).

```
x = 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20
```

```
distance = function(a, b) {
  sqrt(sum((a - b)^2))
}

fun1 = function(x) {
  n = nrow(x)
  results = matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    for (j in seq_len(n)) {
      results[i,j] = distance(m[i,], m[j,])
    }    
  }
  results
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you possibly show us your expected output? It would help to solve your problem. Thank you!

Comment: Are you just looking for `dist(x)` or `as.matrix(dist(x))` to include the whole matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with just a matrix multiplication, some additions and a transpose.

```r
x <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 5)

z <- x %*% t(x)
sqrt(diag(z)+t(diag(z)-2*z))

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    2    4    6    8
#> [2,]    2    0    2    4    6
#> [3,]    4    2    0    2    4
#> [4,]    6    4    2    0    2
#> [5,]    8    6    4    2    0
```

---

Interestingly this is faster than the in built method mentioned in the comments above!

```
mdist <- function(x) {
  z <- x %*% t(x)
  sqrt(diag(z)+t(diag(z)-2*z))
}

n <- 1000
l <- 100
x <- matrix(runif(n*l), ncol = l)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  z1 = as.matrix(dist(x)),
  z2 = dist(x, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE),
  z3 = mdist(x),
  times = 100
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
#>    z1 82.98502 90.20049 98.54552 94.85027 101.78114 140.1809   100
#>    z2 72.54279 76.22054 82.75410 79.31865  83.47765 231.3008   100
#>    z3 54.58258 59.73461 65.62313 63.14435  67.49865 115.0379   100
```

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch, `Vectorize` can do what you need:

```r
outer(seq_len(nrow(m)), seq_len(nrow(m)),
      Vectorize(function(i,j) distance(m[i,], m[j,]), vectorize.args=c("i","j")))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    2    4    6    8
# [2,]    2    0    2    4    6
# [3,]    4    2    0    2    4
# [4,]    6    4    2    0    2
# [5,]    8    6    4    2    0
```

`Vectorize` takes a function as an argument and returns a function that accepts vectors, iterating internally. The function passed to it is called once for each element within the vector passed. By default, `Vectorize` only vectorizes the first argument of the function, but it can "zip" along multiple arguments, assuming they are all the same length, by using `vectorize.args=`.

This might be a little easier to visualize by redefining `distance`:

```r
distance_ind = function(i, j, data) {
  sqrt(sum((data[i,] - data[j,])^2))
}
distance_ind(1, 2, m)
# [1] 2

distance_ind(c(1,3), c(2,3), m)
# [1] 2 ### wrong
distance_ind_vec <- Vectorize(distance_ind, vectorize.args = c("i", "j"))
distance_ind_vec(c(1,3), c(2,3), m)
# [1] 2 0
```

And the `outer` call:

```r
outer(seq_len(nrow(m)), seq_len(nrow(m)), distance_ind_vec, data = m)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    2    4    6    8
# [2,]    2    0    2    4    6
# [3,]    4    2    0    2    4
# [4,]    6    4    2    0    2
# [5,]    8    6    4    2    0
```